# Integrating Multi-Variable Function

Tags: integration

I have the differential equation dv/dt = -kh, where k is a constant but h is a variable. Could I simply integrate each side of the equation with respect to t? Or would this be an illegal operation?

Comment: If h depends on t, then you need to integrate it. I think instead though, that h depends on v. What do these variables represent?

Comment: h is representative of height (variable), t is representative of time (variable) and k is a constant

Answer (score 0):

You should first specify what variables h depends on, anyway allways you can use the chain rule to obtain something like this, I´m speculating about where can your problem being pointing to:

$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dh}\frac{dh}{dt}$

Let be h'(t) = v(t), as commonly is in this problems

$\frac{dv}{dh}\frac{dh}{dt}=-kh$

$v*dv=-kh*dh$

From here you can integrate. Hope I guessed, other way, in the rigorous sense in an integration anithing that isn´t depending on the differential can get out, since linear integration is a Riemman's sum if you´re not summing with respect of h it behaves like a constant inside the integration. Sorry for my bad english